# Arranging all rows of a table based on value of some column, such as rows which have same value of some column needs to be shown together

Tags: sql

## QUESTION

Arranging all rows of a table based on value of some column, such as rows which have same value of some column needs to be shown together

## TABLE

```
EmpId         EmpName        Home Place
101           Ram           Delhi
102           Mohan         Mumbai
103           Shyam         Kolkata
104           Jack          Delhi
105           Sham          Mumbai
```

## VIEW REQUIRED

```
101           Ram           Delhi
104           Jack          Delhi
102           Mohan         Mumbai
105           Sham          Mumbai
103           Shyam         Kolkata
```

Comment: Does it matter if Kolkata comes last or somewhere else, as long as the Delhi rows and the Mumbai rows are kept together?

Comment: @jarlh  yes, it matters. i want the particular value on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach, order by the most common HomePlace first:

```
select EmpId, EmpName, HomePlace
from tablename t1
order by (select count(*) from tablename t2 where t2.HomePlace = t1.HomePlace) desc, HomePlace
```

**Edit**: Order by "kolkata one come first followed by delhi and mumbai", as required:

```
select EmpId, EmpName, HomePlace
from tablename t1
order by case HomePlace when 'Kolkata' then 1
                        when 'Delhi'   then 2
                        when 'Mumbai'  then 3
                        else 4
         end, HomePlace
```

(Note that unknown cities are grouped together in the result order.)

Comment: it's not mandatory that the column value which i want to be first is the most recurring one. It can be even a single occurrence.

Comment: Just tell me how to order. (Can be done with CASE, as in RedFilter's updated answer.)

Comment: order it such that kolkata one come first followed by delhi and mumbai.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the SQL [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) clause:

```
select EmpId, EmpName, Home_Place
from MyTable
order by Home_Place
```

To order with a specific value coming first (e.g., `kolkata`), do this:

```
select EmpId, EmpName, Home_Place
from MyTable
order by case when Home_Place = 'kolkata' then 0 else 1 end,
    Home_Place
```

Comment: order by "Home Place" would be better, since it's ANSI SQL compliant, and no dbms specified. (Works with SQL Server too, if that's what OP uses.)

Comment: Kolkata should come before Mumbai in your query.  He wants them `Group By`, not necessarily `Order By`

Comment: Can we do something where a row with a particular value for a column always comes first.

Comment: @user3611601, yes it can be done, but you have to specify the requirements!

Comment: column name is not an issue, consider it to be home_place.

Comment: when i am using normal order by, you can do either asc or desc. but i want all rows with home_place=kolkata to come first followed by rows of other home_places.

Comment: @user3611601, now you say you want kolkata first, but why is it placed last in your example?